# Vue and Vuex importing module in separate files

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, javascript-objects, node-modules

I think i have a rare question. I've separate main.js and store.js file, so in store.js file i've imported Vuex and setup a new vuex store then exported it. After that, i've imported this file in main.js file and set up its requirement (import Vuex again in main.js and Vue.use(Vuex) here). But it doesn't work in this way. I've to write Vue.use(Vuex) inside store.js file, Otherwise it throws this error: **Error: [vuex] must call Vue.use(Vuex) before creating a store instance.**

main.js file:

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
Vue.use(Vuex);

import App from './App.vue'

import {store} from './store/store.js';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store: store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

and store.js file:

```js
import Vuex from "vuex";

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    counter: 0
  }
});
```

Although i've called `import {store} from './store/store.js';` after Vue.use(Vuex), so Vuex instance inside store.js file doesn't get executed before Vue.use(Vuex)

I suspect that problem is webpack based, but i can't be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `store.js` to import `Vue` and use `Vuex`:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

Vue.use(Vuex);

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    counter: 0
  }
});
```

Then remove `Vue.use(Vuex)` from `main.js` file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

import App from './App.vue' 
import {store} from './store/store.js';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store: store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

It's perfectly okay to have a `use` statement in `store.js`. This is in fact how it would be (at least at one point) generated using a tool like `@vue/cli` if you select the vuex option.

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I know this standard way also, but i want to know what is the problem with my code. Why code doesn't execute successfully in that way?

Comment: @SafarSafarli Are you encountering issues doing it the standard way? Have you examined the `Vue` instance in `store.js` with and without the `use` statement? Yes, it's surrounding how imports and bundling works.

Comment: I think overall this more of a question is less about vue/vuex and more about webpack bundling and resolution. Either way this is most likely a "standard" because of the error you are seeing as a result of webpack resolution of imports.

Comment: Yes, i know several ways to accomplish this issue but, i want to know cause of just this issue, otherwise i will not get satisified. Someone with proper webpack or ES6 modules knowledge may explain the this dark magic behavior.

Comment: I hope you can get your answer. I’ll just say you may have issues getting a detailed answer on the complex inner workings of webpack in combination to specific Vue behavior of plugins. Either way happy coding!

Comment: I've found the origin of the issue, it's ES6 modules related problem, ES6 module implementation (webpack impl) hoists all import statements to the top of the file. So, although you've put Vue.use(Vuex) at the top of file import statements will get hoisted above it.
https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_imports-are-hoisted